# can't set values to text editor

Tags: jquery

```
$('#text-edit').Editor('setText',<?php echo $adsDetails[0]["adText"]; ?>);
```

and it returns something like this

```
$('#text-edit').Editor('setText',<p>test month</p>);
```

It gives error

> "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <"

how to solve this?

Comment: use `$('#text-edit').Editor('setText',"<p>test month</p>");` you have missed `quotes` in `<p>`

Comment: when i use `$('#text-edit').Editor('setText','<?php echo $adsDetails[0]["adText"]; ?>');` it gives error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

Comment: it works with static text. there might be some problem when using dynamic php value.

Comment: anyone have idea how to set html content to line control editor.

Comment: is your code inside a js file?

Answer (score 2):

You have missed `quotes` in `syntax`

```
//use quotes to set html
$('#text-edit').Editor('setText','<p>test month</p>');
```

in your code

```
var text = '<?php echo $adsDetails[0]["adText"]; ?>';
$('#text-edit').Editor('setText','+text+');
```

Comment: i tried your code Miap but it gives error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL"

Comment: @doriyamaulik now thing should work check updated answer.

Comment: thnks parth for your reply. i tried your code but still it gives same error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL"

Comment: @doriyamaulik what html is rendering after this code?

Comment: it creates problem by html content. i am using line-control editor .

Comment: @doriyamaulik what html is generated after applying my code

Comment: value comes with  <p> tag

Comment: @doriyamaulik please check updated code removed double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Change your code as below :

```
<?php $det = $adsDetails[0]["adText"];?>
$("#text-edit").Editor("setText","<?php echo $det;?>");
```

Comment: i tried your code Miap but it gives error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL"

Answer (score 0):

Check this hope it can work

```
$('#text-edit').Editor('setText',<?php echo '$adsDetails[0]["adText"]' ?>);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this 
First assign the text to a hidden field then set it to Editor.
like below.

```
$('#text-edit').Editor('setText',$("#hiddenField").val());
```